# Chart displaying without without any point when only one point available

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using `AmSerialChart` to display chart data. It is working fine when chart data has more than one value. If chart data has only one value, the point and category axis are not displaying. For example, in the below code if I iterate the for loop with more than 1, the points and axis will display fine. But if I set to 1, the point and axis are not displaying. http://jsfiddle.net/arpd17uf/

```
var chartData = generatechartData();

function generatechartData() {
  var chartData = [];
  var firstDate = new Date();     

  for ( var i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
    var newDate = new Date( firstDate );
    newDate.setTime( newDate.getTime() + (i * 60 * 1000) );

    var visits = Math.round( Math.random() * 90 - 45 );

    chartData.push( {
      date: newDate,
      visits: visits
    } );
  }
  return chartData;
}


var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS", 
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "inside": true,
    "axisAlpha": 0
  } ],
  "graphs": [ {
    "id": "g1",
    "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'><span style='font-size:13px;'>[[category]]</span><br>[[value]]</div>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "lineColor": "#fdd400",
    "negativeLineColor": "#67b7dc",
    "valueField": "visits"
  } ],
  "chartScrollbar": {

  },
  "chartCursor": {},
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "minHorizontalGap": 55,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true,
    "position": "top",
    "minPeriod": "fff"
  },
  "listeners": [ {
    "event": "dataUpdated",
    "method": function() {
      if ( chart ) {
        if ( chart.zoomToIndexes ) {
          chart.zoomToIndexes( 130, chartData.length - 1 );
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your minPeriod is too small. Your data is in minute intervals, going by your setTime calculations, so you'll want to set it to minutes (`"mm"`), rather than milliseconds (`"fff"`).

```
  "categoryAxis": {
    // ... omitted
    "minPeriod": "mm"
  },
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arpd17uf/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick observation. Actually sometimes the data with timestamp differs in milliseconds also hence I have added minPeriod as "fff". Can you please suggest how to display single data point with milliseconds. For example [http://jsfiddle.net/arpd17uf/2/]

Comment: In that case, set [equalSpacing](http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#equalSpacing) to true in your categoryAxis. This will re-adjust the axis accordingly. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arpd17uf/4/)

Comment: Thanks you so much its perfect now